# php/mysql special tree

Tags: php, mysql, tree

I was messing arround with code and i can't figure out to do this:

[image: Node Tree]

I have a Table in the database like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `nodetree` ( 
 `node` int(11) NOT NULL, 
 `prevnode` int(11) NOT NULL, 
 `nextnode` int(11) NOT NULL, 
 `nodename` varchar(30) NOT NULL, 
 `nodelink` varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
 PRIMARY KEY (`node`,`prevnode`, `nextnode`) 
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

What i want to do is to get php build that graph automatically with tables. Each node is a clickable link to node description.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1, Great question (wish I had more upvotes)

Comment: you can still output it as a tree, but for each node should make an extra column where you can put in an array something called like `relations` , in there you define the additional parent_id's (relation_ids)

Answer (score 3):

By definition a node in a tree can only have one parent.  But that isn't the case in your example.  What you really have here is a directed graph, not a tree.  You might want to have a look at [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Modeling_DAGs_on_SQL_DBs.aspx) for a good example of how to represent and query a graph in SQL.

Comment: That's right. A tree is a special type of graph and that's not a tree.